# Edit header in '.eml'

Tags: python-3.x, email, parsing, email-headers

As a brief summary, I have a bunch of '.eml' files in a directory. I need to forward these emails back to 'email@example.com'.

The problem is that the field 'From' in the header of the '.eml' file contains another email address which doesn't match with 'email@example.com'.

I've searched for a way to parse the file and update the content of the header.

At first, I was using the following modules:

- *eml.parser* to parse the file.
- *pyo365* to connect to MSGraph API

I was able to send the content of the body but when I would try to send the attachments, I had to decode from base64 and extract the attachments in a folder, then send everything. I **did not need to change the content** of the header.

I know this was a bad move because there is probably a way to send the attachments encoded.

Also, since MSGraph attachment's file size limit is 4mb per requests, I decided to try to change for:

- *smtplib* to send the email
- I tried *mail-parser* without success to update anything in the content since the updated values would not be permanent, for instance:

  mail = mailparser.parse_from_bytes(byte_mail)
  mail.from_ = [('My Name' , 'email@example.com')]
  print(mail.headers) #This would print the original header

I also tried with mail.update() and various method using this module without success.

I found a post [Python: Modify Values in eml file (email header)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543395/python-modify-values-in-eml-file-email-header) which suggested to use Parser, replace_header and as_string from *email* but I was unable to make it work either as I wouldn't be able to call *replace_header* and *as_string*:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage #contains as_string
from email.parser import HeaderParser
file = open(filename, 'r')
h = HeaderParser().parse(file)

#stuck here
```

I know this is probably not only one question but the main goal is to send eml files back to a particular address, from 'email@example.com'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by parsing the email with *eml_parser*. I created my own header, attached the HTML body content and the attachments.

```
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.header import Header

def send(self, dst):
    try:
        self.m = MIMEMultipart()
        self.m['From'] = self.client_addr
        self.m['To'] = dst
        # Must have Header() in python 3.x otherwise you get UnicodeError
        self.m['Subject'] = Header(self.get_subject(),  'utf-8')

        #Attach HTML body with the right encoding
        self.m.attach(MIMEText(self.get_body().encode('utf-8'), 'html', 'utf-8'))

        # Extract attachments to self.attachment_path
        self.extract_attachments(self.parsed_eml)

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()

        # Compare hash in config.json file
        if self.pwd_context.verify(self.client_plain_secret, self.client_secret):

            server.login(self.client_addr, self.client_plain_secret)
            server.sendmail(self.m['From'], self.m['To'], self.m.as_string())
            server.quit()
    except:
        print("An error occured trying to send the email.")
    finally:
        self.clean_attachments()
```